# Left join to a SET using linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

In SQL, I would commonly inner join two or more tables to create a **set** and then left join to that **set**:

```
select *
from TableA
left outer join
   TableB
   inner join TableC on TableB.Id = TableC.TableBId
on TableA.Id = TableB.TableAId
```

What is the Linq equivalent of this? I'm using EF Code First.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by breaking it into two statements. First, make your inner join set, then left join to that set.

```
var bc = from b in TableB
         join c in TableC on b.Id equals c.TableBId
         select new { B = b, C = c };

var result = from a in TableA
             from bcRow in bc.Where(row => a.Id equals row.B.TableAId).DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { A = a, B = bcRow.B, C = bcRow.C };
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var result = from a in TableA
             join b in TableB on a.Id equals b.TableAId into ab
             from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join c in TableC on b.Id equals c.TableBId
             select a;
```

Comment: There isn't even a left join in that query. You just inner joined them all together. Please read the question.

Comment: Wouldn't this throw a null reference exception? If b is null, b.Id would error, would it not?

Comment: it will not give exception

Comment: This gives incorrect results. I want to left join A to the inner joined set of B and C like the example I gave. This generates sql that inner joins C _outside_ of the left join which, in effect, makes the left join act like an inner join.